# How to create a ''for loop'' to download 5 consecutive months of data?

Tags: r, for-loop

For an assignment we are supposed to use a for-loop to obtain a dataframe of 5 consecutive months.
The data regards crimes and their accompanying type of crime, location, month, street name etc.

How do we go about this issue?

We use the package 'ukpolice' and use this code to obtain data for a specific month and location of choice;

ukpolice syntax is as follows:

```
data <- as.data.frame(ukc_crime_location(lat = , lng = , date = ""))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi,  people will help you but you need to also show that you are trying.  So can you show us how you think a for loop in r works and also what variable do you think you would need to manipulate to change the month.  Why don't you try writing the code to get a single month of data to start.

Comment: You can edit your question or type comments.